# Is there a way to have self, message, and ctx in an on_message event?

Tags: python, pymongo, discord.py

Right now, I am using cogs to make an emoji filter. To use the on_message event to check if people are spamming emojis, I need to have self, message, and ctx as args in the on_message event. (the reason I need ctx is to check the guild id in mongodb, which is what im using to store whether the server has enlisted in the filter system). My code is

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message, ctx):
        existing = collection.find_one({"serverid": ctx.guild.id})
        if not existing:
            return
        else:
            if message.author.bot:
                return
            s = message.content
            s2 = message.content.lower()
            message.content = re.sub("[_~*]", "", message.content)
            message.content = re.sub(r"[\s]+[\s]{2}", "", message.content)
            if emoji_count == 1 and len(without_emojis) < 10:
                current = message.created_at.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
                bucket = self._buckets1.get_bucket(message, current)
                retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit(current)
                if retry_after:
                    await message.delete()
```

The command to start using the filter system works fine, but the on_message event throws an error, no matter the order I have tried to replace it in.

Here's the error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'`

If anyone knows how to fix the error, I would appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is an `on_event` listener, there is no `ctx` being passed to your function. Think of the arguments of an event listener as less of a menu where you can order what you want and more of you just being able to name the few things it is passing to you. So keep the `message` argument, as that is the one being passed to the function internally from the library and remove the `ctx` argument.

That being said, `ctx` is **nothing but an easier way to access things** everything that is accessible with `ctx` can be found some other way. As you want the guild id, this is quite easy with the message object:

```py
guild_id = message.channel.guild.id
```

Comment: This is correct, but as an alternative, there is a way get `ctx` in the `on_message` event. You can use [get_context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context)

Comment: @Benjin Good Point! I forgot about that one